# How do I make pandas treat each row as a column based on a certain date variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to rotate my pandas dataframe so that my data that looks like...

```
     date   | data_1 | data_2 | data_3 | data_4
-----------------------------------------------
'2017-04-01'|     100|     200|     300|    400
'2017-05-01'|     500|     222|     333|    444
```

to look like...

```
       | '2017-04-01' | '2017-05-01'
------------------------------------
data_1 |           100|          500
data_2 |           200|          222 
data_3 |           300|          333
data_4 |           400|          444
```

I've been looking at pivoting the data frame, but I can't figure out what the "index" would be.  When I tried to add an index value to each row I tried this pivot:

```
pd.pivot(index='index', 
        columns='date', 
        values=['data_1', 'data_2', 'data_3', 'data_4'])
```

but it gave me an error saying `Length of index, columns and values must be the same`.

I'm clearly out of my depth here.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `set_index` + `transpose`:

```
res = df.set_index('date').T

print(res)

date    '2017-04-01'  '2017-05-01'
data_1           100           500
data_2           200           222
data_3           300           333
data_4           400           444
```

So you do not need to use `pivot_table`, which is almost exclusively reserved for when you need to perform aggregations based on a pivot. Note property `T` is an accessor to the method `transpose()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  It was apparently a duplicate question.  I thought I had searched pretty well but I apparently didn't.  Thanks again!